# Elastic search node.js proxy request freezed

Tags: express, elasticsearch, proxy, webpack

i tried to make request to elastic search server (localhost:9200) from my server localhost:8080, but when I'am doing that there is no response from elastic search, code :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
// var esClient = require('../db/esProvider');
var proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

router.use('/:apiKey/_search', proxy({
    target: 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
    changeOrigin:true,
    pathRewrite: function (path, req) {
        return path.replace('/api', '')
    },
    onProxyReq: function (proxyReq, req, res) {
      console.log('request')
    },
    onProxyRes: function (proxyRes, req, res) {
        // add new header to response
        console.log('resoponse')
    },
    onError:function(err, req, res){
        console.log(err)
    }
}));
```

what's wrong with my proxy config, when i try to create proxy server via webpack-dev-server, I receive normal response...

Answer (score 0):

oh, sorry, it was body-parser problem, i was sending POST request after applying body-parser middleware, that's why proxy server sent invalid body to elastic search